# Are server side functions supported in DSE graph?

Tags: javascript, java, user-defined-functions, datastax-enterprise, datastax-enterprise-graph

I am using dse-5.0.5 with dse-studio and have some authorization gremlin queries that should be executed before any query in DSE graph so are server side functions supported in DSE graph so as to speed up the processing and avoid calling function from code every now and then.

If they are where can I find the documentation of the same?

--Thanks

Varun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DSE Graph supports Strategies and VertexProperty programs.  A Custom Strategy could be used to achieve what you are attempting to do.  See this blog for details - http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/gremlins-time-machine.